# Возможно ли создать ram-disk для своего приложения, аналогия виртуальный диск на PC

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio, ram

Возможно ли создать собственный виртуальный диск на андроид устройстве через свое приложение, аналогия на PC можно создать вирутальный диск и запаролить.

Comment: Так ram-disk или виртуальный диск? Просто ram-disk нет смысла запароливать, он при отключении испаряется вникуда.

Comment: Да, точно виртуальный